# I want to remove box for mobile view

Tags: html, css

This is the html file:

```
            <div className={styles.box}>
                <div className={styles.video}>
                    <video poster="/gif/something.gif" controls width="100%" height="400">
                        <source src="/video/something.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
                        I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the css for it:

```
.video{
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .box{
        display: none;
    }
}

.box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 50px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    shape-outside: border-box;
    box-shadow: 30px 30px #7493DC;;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: block;

}
```

What I want is that after a certain pixel, I want the video stay but the box should be removed, so the video can take the entire screen.

Comment: If you hide a parent element, it's content will also be hidden. You may want to try restyling the `.box` to meet your needs instead of hiding it (Also, media queries should generally come after the default style in the CSS document)

Comment: I do want the video inside the box ( for laptop views ) that is why I tried to structure it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```css
.box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 50px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    shape-outside: border-box;
    box-shadow: 30px 30px #7493DC;;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: block;

}
.video{
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .box{
        margin:0;
        border:0;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Take screen more than 767px to view the box div</p>
 <div class="box">
     <div class="video">
         <video  autoplay muted loop  controls width="100%" height="400">
         
         <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         
         I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
         </video>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please add `box` style written before the media query in 767px .

Comment: ordering of class has no relation with media query

Comment: @gpl Media queries have no specificity of their own, but a `.box` rule with the same specificity further down the document will take priority over one at the top. (Not that this really solves the problem on it's own, but it is relevant)

Comment: @DBS totally agree, but there is no duplicate `.box` there and media rule is applied for their displays  of certain width only. Actually he just put CSS for `.video` class below the `.box`. So those changes are irrelevant.

Comment: @GAURAV SHARMA Please refer this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/mdPRQKW)

Comment: @RayeesAC I do want to run the video even if the size is less I just do not want to show the margins and this code is not doing that.

Comment: Check now bro :)

Comment: Thank you very much, just one small thing I want the video to be on the center of the screen. Can you help with that too.@RayeesAC

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .box  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This media rule apply to only screen whose width is less than 600px (most mobile display width < 600px). You can alter this screen-width limit according to your needs. Inside the rule we are setting `display: none;` for the `box` class which will hide the box.